# Ping 100 ms in one direction 200 ms when opposite

Tags: ping

We have 2 independent networks and a few users in network A use remote desktop to get on a terminal server in network B.  We set up an IPSec tunnel between the 2.  As far as we can tell the bandwidths on either side aren't reaching their limits, so we haven't set up any dedicated bandwidth rules on the routers or firewalls.

When users on network A ping the public IP or private IP of the terminal server in network B, they get 100 ms responses.  When on the server in network B and pinging back to network A, ping times are 200 ms.

Comment: You didn't really ask a question there. Are you asking why is it 100 ms longer the opposite way?

Comment: @MrStatic given the subject of the post I'd say so.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely it is down to routing somewhere. Do a traceroute from either side and see which router is adding in the extra time.